# Android 6.0 Direct Share doesn't work in one project but does in the next

Tags: java, android

I have a bit of a predicament. I am trying to implement the Android 6.0 Direct Sharing feature to my app. However, when I implemented it, the direct share targets did not show up. I decided to try putting the exact same code into a different app of mine and it worked perfectly. Does anyone have any ideas why it would work on one but not the next?

Here is the manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".DirectShareReceiver"
            android:label="Direct Share Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
                android:value=".PluginChooserTargetService" />
        </activity>

<service android:name=".PluginChooserTargetService"
            android:label="PluginDirectShare"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: What is your targetSDKversion of each projects? Please show your code in onGetChooserTargets(), it will may help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the code most of worked in a older version of android. Android 6.0+ has a new way of setting permissions.

You will need to use the new permission for [newer versions of android](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) (6.0+).

Here is some examples from the site:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```